# Clicking on the language button removes the id params in the URL

Tags: internationalization, routes, cakephp-1.3

So here's my problem. I have a website that we're currently translating in french using cakephp. When I am on a page with a url such as "www.mydomain.com/eng/store/view/1" The url I see in the french language link is "www.mydomain.com/fre/store/view/".

Here's my code in my routes.php that is related to the store page

```
Router::connect('/:language/:controller/:action/*',
                   array(),
                   array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
Router::connect('/store/:action/*', array('controller'=>'products'));
Router::connect('/store', array('controller'=>'products', 'action'=>'index'));
```

In my app_helper.php I have

```
function url($url = null, $full = false) {
        if(!isset($url['language']) && isset($this->params['language'])) {
          $url['language'] = $this->params['language'];
        }     

        return parent::url($url, $full);
    }
```

So my question is: what should I do to make my link keep the last params of the product when switching language?

Note: The link works perfectly for pages with only a controller and an action in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the actual problem why my parameters were not following in the language link. I'm not entirely sure this is the best option, but it works for me.

When adding the links for the language instead of having :

```
echo $this->Html->link('English', array('language'=>'eng'))
```

I am using

```
echo $this->Html->link('English', array('language'=>'eng')+$this->params['pass']);
```

Looking to see if there was a routing issue was not entirely useless as I have found many flaw that made other pages that would not go to the correct url, mainly the pages under the pages folder. Adding

```
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
Router::connect('/:language/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'), array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
```

Did the trick for these.

Answer (score 0):

This works in all the cases and passing variable:

```
Router::connect('/action/**', array('controller' => 'controller_name', 'action'=>'action_name'));
```

Here if you want to limit your url and add variable to your url =>e.g. controller/action/variable

```
 Router::connect('/action/:id', array('controller' => 'controller_name', 'action'=>'action_name')
                              , array('pass'=>array('id')));
```

[Here is reference](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html)

hope it helps

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I have tried your solution and I have read the reference. I have a better understanding of the routing and how it works but sadly it seems like it's not what I need for this specific situation. The params at the end are still getting cut off when you click on the french or english button. I believe there might be something else that I'm missing.